Adding CA to the SSLContext
I am trying to connect with quickfix via SSL and I want to add a chain of certificates programmatically to the SSLContext in quickfix.mina.ssl.SSLContextFactory. I can initialize the keystore and trustmanager just fine but there doesn't seem to be a setting that can read a .cer file that has the chain of certificates to be added to the trust manager. Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Just out of curiosity: why don't you add the certificates to a keystore file? Why do you want to do it programatically?

Hi @ChristophJohn I am bringing this app up in a k8s pod with a mounted location that has the certificate file in it, so instead of doing cli gymnastics with an initcontainer or some startup script prior to loading the app it would be much easier to load the file and inject the certificates programmatically into the SSLContext
